# Holding a cup 'upright'. Holding a spoon [word]?

Tags: word-request

**Holding a cup *upright*** is what we say when we want that whatever is in the cup remains in the cup (when sb. holds it in their hands).

So then, what is the corresponding word if it's not a cup but a spoon?

Holding a spoon ***WORD*** ?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey -- sounds good. Please add it as an answer so that I can at least upvote it. I have accepted 'level' as the answer but 'straight' sounds good too and makes total sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to keep soup in a spoon, then you're

## holding a spoon level

Comment: Nice work.  You could also say something more technical-sounding, such as "horizontal" or "parallel to the <whatever>".  Note that "holding a spoon flat" would be understood by most, too.

Comment: @Fattie Yep, all those are correct too, just not as natural. You could post each one as a separate answer and let the voters decide

Comment: @gotube - perfect! I did not want 'horizontal' etc, as those terms sound too technical.